# Java: Does primitive type casts performance impact?

Tags: java, performance, primitive

Is it faster to assign a `long` value to an `int` variable using a cast or is using a `long` variable faster?

Or it is a choice, between consuming more memory and processing more?

Here is an example test:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class NanoTest {
    final int loop = 20000;

    public void testNoCasting() {
        long sum = 0;
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            sum += System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    public void testIntCasting() {
        int sum = 0;
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            sum += (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NanoTest nt = new NanoTest();

    Instant start = Instant.now();

        nt.testNoCasting(); // or nt.testIntCasting();

        Instant end = Instant.now();

        System.out.print("Duration: ");
        System.out.println(Duration.between(start, end).getNano());

    }
}
```

Comment: What did your test reveal?

Comment: There are really better ways to test the performance of the JVM, you know...

Comment: Hello Vivin, the another question is about object cast,  my doubt is about primitive types. thanks.

Comment: why don't you use **System.nanoTime();** which it is more accurate?

Comment: I suspect the execution time is too small to be measured using milliseconds. I suggest you try executing thousands of cast operations, not one at a time.

Comment: The `currentTimeMillis()` is just for sum and cast. To print I'm use the nano time (`between(start, end).getNano()`). The result varies between 1000000-3000000 nanos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A typecast from long to int just ignores the leading 32 bit, so it should be more or less for free.

Long (=64 bit) operations are more expensive on 32 bit CPUs -- a 32 bit CPU will need two machine instructions to add two 64 bit numbers (other operations may take many more). On 64 bit CPUs, there shouldn't be a difference in terms of CPU time.

The (implicit) cast the other way around (from int to long) requires a "[sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension)", which means the high bits are filled from the highest bit of the smaller type. So it may actually have a (small) cost, as it is not just ignoring the high bits, but needs to bring them into a well-defined state.

Comment: This level of explanation that I wanted to have. Thanks.

Comment: a 32bit CPu certainly uses _much_ more instructions for 64bit operations - you're using the term incorrectly. Even the most trivial operations usually include several instructions, some even result in thousands of instructions (like hardware AES decryption / encryption) for one single operation.

Comment: You are right -- I was just talking about addition (because that's used in the example). I think a multiplication should take four, and then for more complex operations this adds up accordingly. I have updated the answer accordingly.